# PT10 - less tracks ? Still single display?

Tags: daw, pro-tools-10

I purchased PT9 about 8 months ago, but never really get started to use it... yeah, not a wise expense...  To get workflow going, I just sticked with Sonar X1 and waited for a 'downtime' that never came yet...

Now, 8 months later, I look at the specs and a few points strike me. Among those: maximum 32 simultaneous tracks ??... was this the same limit with PT9 ? (Yet, I never went there, but I have projects well around or over 40 tracks with Sonar and the limit is... what your system can achieve!!...

I see nothing about a real friendly integration of dual (or more) displays. Going 2-monitors with PT9 was 'kind of' feasible, not exactely friendly or value-added. Has this evolved in PT10?

I now realize that some cool features I had seen in studios equipped with PTHD are working only in ... PTHD (write on stop, and some editing features...) - My decision to buy PT9 standalone was essentially... such features!!...

Bottom line, ok I have not done my homeworks... But just out of curiosity: is PT10 standalone (that is, not the high-end HD systems) offering less than PT9 ??

Thanks,
DorbicheOne

Answer (score 1):

"32 simultaneous tracks" are you referring to recording or playback? Obviously it has far more for editing/mixing capabilities. Some cool new features were added to PT10 but it's probably best if you just checked out Avid's site or YouTube to see for yourself what it can do ;)

Not really sure what you mean by the dual screen integration either? Probably the best DAW out there for using 2 screens! Just the edit and mix window (unless you do much MIDI/scoring)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen triple-display setups in PT (edit+mix+video). In fact this is more common than not.

PT9/10 [has](http://www.avid.com/US/products/family/pro-tools/compare) more tracks than that. You can *record* up to 32 simultaneous, and play up to 96, depending on your project sample rate. There are features in 10 which make it worth upgrading from 9, however if you're not really using 9 then you won't be missing much of what 10 has to offer.

Sonar's is a much more recent interface design, while Pro Tools has a lot of legacy to carry through. Could be PT feels limited in terms of multiple display flexibility, but I haven't seen that get in the way. Haven't even thought about it.

Re if PT 10 has *less* to offer than PT 9 - in short: No. Clip gain, the new channel strip, AudioSuite handles. These three don't look very big in text. (I mean who needs yet another channel strip, right?, and clip gain and render handles are old news). But with the three combined, my PT10 sessions look nothing like PT9 and earlier.

If you're looking to do video-related work, I don't think Sonar has much ground in that market, so spare yourself the frustration of finding out. Add PT to your workflow without switching over from X1.

Answer (score 1):

I have PT9 And I use 3 displays.  1 is my edit window, 2 is my mix window/ workspace folder structures , which is offset to the side of my desk near my control surface and 3 is used for video playback/durrough meters etc.

What I am more worried about with PT 10 and the clip gain and new channel strips is how it will react when you open it in any other version of PT.  It would be lots of work to lose, all of your clip based gain when you have to open it on an older PT system like I would for the dub stages here.

I'm curious how the flow between 10 and older systems reacts.  I know PT 9 I have never had a problem with opening it in PT 8

Comment: @michael I attended a demo seminar and asked the question about clip gain compatibility with older versions. It was explained to me that you have the option to render the gain changes to new audio files when moving to PT9 and earlier. unsure about the channel strips.

Comment: @Jinksi  I wonder if its possible to copy trim plugin gain automation and have it apply to clips some how....I do not like the idea of printing to new audio files.  A friend of mine just won a copy of PT10 from an avid seminar....she doesn't do sound so I am going to temporarily appropriate it for research purposes :P